# vb.net system.threading.thread ask the thread to cleanup and stop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am new to vb.net multithreading, and I am facing a issue. 
For threading I am using `system.threading.thread` function.

I know I can stop a thread using `thread.abort` call. But that's not a good choice (I have searched a bit and came to know that). This also will not work because my running threads needs some cleanup before cancellation.

So, I'm trying to do some kind of action that set a variable to UI thread like

```
dim bolStop as Boolean
```

So, if my UI thread set that Boolean value as true then all running thread can access/notice that change and can start cleanup process before stop/cancel the thread itself.

hope that makes sense...

best regards

Edit:1 (Source Is Pasted Here as Suggested By @DrunkenCodeMonkey

This is the code for Main Form (Form1.vb) (I think i need something here and also on the thread module (class) too) so, below i will paste module code too

```
Public Class Form1
Private objThreadList As ArrayList
Dim bolStop As Boolean
Private Sub cmd1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd1.Click
    Dim intTLoop As Integer
    sPrepareThreading()

    For intTLoop = 1 To 5
        sSendThread("", "Zakir", "Biplob")
    Next
    'sFinishThreading()
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
End Sub

Sub sPrepareThreading()
    Dim intTLoop As Integer
    objThreadList = New ArrayList
    For intTLoop = 1 To 3
        objThreadList.Add(Nothing)
    Next intTLoop
End Sub

Sub sSendThread(strDraft As String, ByVal strTitle As String, ByVal strSubHeader As String)
    Dim bolFalied As Boolean
    Dim intTLoop As Integer
    Dim objItem As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
    Dim objTData As objThreadCrossData
    Dim objThreadClass As clsThread
    Dim objNewThread As System.Threading.Thread

Zakir_RecheckThread:
    My.Application.DoEvents()
    If bolStop = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    bolFalied = True
    For intTLoop = 1 To 3
        bolFalied = True
        If objThreadList(intTLoop - 1) Is Nothing Then
            bolFalied = False
        Else
            If CType(objThreadList(intTLoop - 1), System.Threading.Thread).IsAlive = False Then
                bolFalied = False
            Else
                bolFalied = True
            End If
        End If
        If bolFalied = False Then
            objTData = New objThreadCrossData
            objTData.ID = ListView1.Items.Count
            objTData.bolStop = False
            objTData.strTime = DateTime.Now.ToString
            objItem = ListView1.Items.Add(strTitle)
            objItem.SubItems.Add(strSubHeader)
            objItem = Nothing
            objThreadClass = New clsThread(objTData, "", Me)
            objNewThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf objThreadClass.StartThread)
            objNewThread.IsBackground = True
            objNewThread.Start()
            objThreadList(intTLoop - 1) = objNewThread
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If bolFalied = True Then
        GoTo Zakir_RecheckThread
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ReceiveThreadMessage(ByVal objCrosData As Object)
    Dim objTDataV1 As objThreadCrossData
    objTDataV1 = CType(objCrosData, objThreadCrossData)
    ListView1.Items(objTDataV1.ID).SubItems(1).Text = objTDataV1.strProgress
End Sub

Private Sub cmd2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd2.Click
    REM This is where i like to stop the running thred either by setting bolStop = True and all running thead check that variable.
    REM or by chate the thread (Thread Data Object Property naemd "bolStop" value"

    REM please help me out...

End Sub
End Class
```

Code For Thread Module (clsThread.vb):

```
Public Class clsThread
Private m_Counter As Integer = 0
Private m_MainWindow As Form
Dim m_ThreadCrorssData As objThreadCrossData
Private Delegate Sub NotifyMainWindow(ByVal objCrosData As objThreadCrossData)
'We need an object of this deletegate
Private m_NotifyMainWindow As NotifyMainWindow

Public Sub New(ByVal objCrossData As Object, ByVal strXML As String, ByRef MainWindow As Form1)
    m_MainWindow = MainWindow
    m_ThreadCrorssData = CType(objCrossData, objThreadCrossData)
    'We need to point our delegate to the Method, which we want to call from this thread
    m_NotifyMainWindow = AddressOf MainWindow.ReceiveThreadMessage
End Sub

Public Sub StartThread()
    While m_Counter < 100
        m_Counter = m_Counter + 1
        rem for example here i like to check for the value that whether user asked to stop
        m_ThreadCrorssData.strProgress = CStr(m_Counter)
        m_MainWindow.Invoke(m_NotifyMainWindow, m_ThreadCrorssData)
        rem for example also here i like to check for the value that whether user asked to stop
        'wait for some time before continuing loop
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the Code For Module (Thread Object Data)

```
Module mdlCMM
Public Class objThreadCrossData
    Property strProgress As String
    Property bolStop As Boolean = False
    Property strTime As String
    Property ID As Integer
    Property intStatusNum As Integer
    Property strStatusValue As String
End Class
End Module
```

Comment: What are your threads doing? Are they polling threads? Those (or abnormally long running threads) are pretty much the only kind you would need to abort. I would just let short-running threads finish gracefully and let the GC handle things rather than abort them. For a polling thread, I would call Thread.Abort, catch the ThreadAbortedException and do the cleanup from there. In any case some example code showing your program flow would help answer you better.

Comment: i am looking for something like lock Boolean or so. I am not sure whats that call. However as suggested by @DrunkenCodeMonkey here is the link to download my source project. It's in zip file that contains vb.net 2010 source project files.

here is the link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nr2xyfrabuaegoq/Thread%20Test%2003.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please post only the relevant bits of code... Nobody really wants to have to download a compressed binary and open up a project and then try to find the relevant area.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey, sir, please check now i have added source to the main post now.. thanks for your suggestion...